# AH01070: Error parsing script headers in PHP-FPM when accessing certain product detail pages in development mode

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, magento2.3.2

So I am getting after some probably unrelated changes the error

```
[Wed Sep 04 16:00:18.155246 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22240] [client 192.168.0.160:35618] AH01070: Error parsing script headers
[Wed Sep 04 16:00:18.155251 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22240] (22)Invalid argument: [client 192.168.0.160:35618] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :
```

In the apache error log.

I am running on PHP7.1 via FPM.

After hours of debugging, and finally replacing the `header()` calls  in `\Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response::sendHeaders` with `echo` calls, it turns out that Magento tries to send this header:

```
X-Magento-Tags: cat_c,cat_c_139,cat_c_172,cat_c_189,cat_c_196,cat_c_210,cat_c_333,cat_c_327,store,cms_b,cms_b_footer_service_links,cms_b_footer_social_links,cms_b_footer_links_1,cms_b_footer_links_2,cms_b_footer_links_3,cms_b_footer_imprint_privacy,cat_p_3280,cat_p,cat_p_496,cat_p_1494,cat_p_1114,cat_p_1389,cat_p_2347,cat_p_2350,cat_p_1355,cat_p_1261,cat_p_1327,cat_p_2812,cat_p_1574,cat_p_1470,cat_p_1472,cat_p_1228,cat_p_1227,cat_p_1203,cat_p_1205,cat_p_1248,cat_p_395,cat_p_1318,cat_p_2882,cat_p_2881,cat_p_2876,cat_p_2872,cat_p_2880,cat_p_2879,cat_p_2875,cat_p_2871,cat_c_p_139,cat_p_3291,cat_p_3279,cat_p_3278,cat_p_3277,cat_p_3244,cat_p_3241,cat_p_3240,cat_p_3239,cat_p_3238,cat_p_3237,cat_p_3236,cat_p_3235,cat_p_3234,cat_p_3233,cat_p_3232,cat_p_3231,cat_p_3230,cat_p_3229,cat_p_3228,cat_p_3227,cat_p_3226,cat_p_3225,cat_p_3224,cat_p_3223,cat_p_3222,cat_p_3221,cat_p_3220,cat_p_3219,cat_p_3218,cat_p_3217,cat_p_3216,cat_p_3215,cat_p_3214,cat_p_3213,cat_p_3212,cat_p_3211,cat_p_3210,cat_p_3209,cat_p_3208,cat_p_3207,cat_p_3206,cat_p_3205,cat_p_3204,cat_p_3203,cat_p_3202,cat_p_3201,cat_p_3200,cat_p_3199,cat_p_3198,cat_p_3197,cat_p_3196,cat_p_3195,cat_p_3194,cat_p_3193,cat_p_3192,cat_p_3191,cat_p_3190,cat_p_3189,cat_p_3188,cat_p_3187,cat_p_3186,cat_p_3185,cat_p_3184,cat_p_3183,cat_p_3182,cat_p_3181,cat_p_3180,cat_p_3179,cat_p_3178,cat_p_3177,cat_p_3176,cat_p_3175,cat_p_3174,cat_p_3173,cat_p_3172,cat_p_3171,cat_p_3170,cat_p_3169,cat_p_3168,cat_p_3167,cat_p_3166,cat_p_3165,cat_p_3164,cat_p_3163,cat_p_3162,cat_p_3161,cat_p_3160,cat_p_3159,cat_p_3158,cat_p_3157,cat_p_3156,cat_p_3155,cat_p_3154,cat_p_3153,cat_p_3152,cat_p_3151,cat_p_3150,cat_p_3149,cat_p_3148,cat_p_3147,cat_p_3146,cat_p_3145,cat_p_3144,cat_p_3143,cat_p_3142,cat_p_3141,cat_p_3140,cat_p_3139,cat_p_3138,cat_p_3137,cat_p_3136,cat_p_3135,cat_p_3134,cat_p_3133,cat_p_3132,cat_p_3131,cat_p_3130,cat_p_3129,cat_p_3128,cat_p_3127,cat_p_3126,cat_p_3125,cat_p_3124,cat_p_3123,cat_p_3122,cat_p_3121,cat_p_3120,cat_p_3119,cat_p_3118,cat_p_3117,cat_p_3116,cat_p_3115,cat_p_3114,cat_p_3113,cat_p_3112,cat_p_3111,cat_p_3110,cat_p_3109,cat_p_3108,cat_p_3107,cat_p_3106,cat_p_3105,cat_p_3104,cat_p_3103,cat_p_3102,cat_p_3101,cat_p_3100,cat_p_3099,cat_p_3098,cat_p_3097,cat_p_3096,cat_p_3095,cat_p_3094,cat_p_3093,cat_p_3092,cat_p_3091,cat_p_3090,cat_p_3089,cat_p_3088,cat_p_3087,cat_p_3086,cat_p_3085,cat_p_3084,cat_p_3082,cat_p_3081,cat_p_3080,cat_p_3079,cat_p_3078,cat_p_3077,cat_p_3076,cat_p_3075,cat_p_3074,cat_p_3073,cat_p_3072,cat_p_3071,cat_p_3070,cat_p_3069,cat_p_3068,cat_p_3067,cat_p_3066,cat_p_3065,cat_p_3064,cat_p_3063,cat_p_3062,cat_p_3061,cat_p_3060,cat_p_3059,cat_p_3058,cat_p_3057,cat_p_3056,cat_p_3055,cat_p_3054,cat_p_3053,cat_p_3052,cat_p_3051,cat_p_3050,cat_p_3049,cat_p_3048,cat_p_3047,cat_p_3046,cat_p_3045,cat_p_3044,cat_p_3043,cat_p_3042,cat_p_3041,cat_p_3040,cat_p_3039,cat_p_3038,cat_p_3037,cat_p_3036,cat_p_3035,cat_p_3034,cat_p_3033,cat_p_3032,cat_p_3031,cat_p_3030,cat_p_3029,cat_p_3028,cat_p_3027,cat_p_3026,cat_p_3025,cat_p_3024,cat_p_3023,cat_p_3022,cat_p_3021,cat_p_3020,cat_p_3019,cat_p_3018,cat_p_3017,cat_p_3016,cat_p_3015,cat_p_3014,cat_p_3013,cat_p_3012,cat_p_3011,cat_p_3010,cat_p_3009,cat_p_3008,cat_p_3007,cat_p_3006,cat_p_3005,cat_p_3004,cat_p_3003,cat_p_3002,cat_p_3001,cat_p_3000,cat_p_2999,cat_p_2998,cat_p_2997,cat_p_2996,cat_p_2994,cat_p_2993,cat_p_2992,cat_p_2991,cat_p_2990,cat_p_2989,cat_p_2988,cat_p_2987,cat_p_2986,cat_p_2985,cat_p_2984,cat_p_2983,cat_p_2982,cat_p_2981,cat_p_2980,cat_p_2979,cat_p_2978,cat_p_2977,cat_p_2976,cat_p_2975,cat_p_2974,cat_p_2973,cat_p_2972,cat_p_2971,cat_p_2970,cat_p_2969,cat_p_2968,cat_p_2967,cat_p_2966,cat_p_2965,cat_p_2964,cat_p_2963,cat_p_2962,cat_p_2961,cat_p_2960,cat_p_2959,cat_p_2958,cat_p_2957,cat_p_2956,cat_p_2955,cat_p_2954,cat_p_2953,cat_p_2952,cat_p_2951,cat_p_2950,cat_p_2949,cat_p_2948,cat_p_2947,cat_p_2946,cat_p_2945,cat_p_2944,cat_p_2943,cat_p_2942,cat_p_2941,cat_p_2940,cat_p_2939,cat_p_2938,cat_p_2937,cat_p_2936,cat_p_2935,cat_p_2934,cat_p_2933,cat_p_2932,cat_p_2931,cat_p_2930,cat_p_2929,cat_p_2928,cat_p_2927,cat_p_2926,cat_p_2925,cat_p_2924,cat_p_2923,cat_p_2922,cat_p_2921,cat_p_2920,cat_p_2919,cat_p_2918,cat_p_2917,cat_p_2916,cat_p_2915,cat_p_2914,cat_p_2913,cat_p_2912,cat_p_2911,cat_p_2910,cat_p_2909,cat_p_2908,cat_p_2907,cat_p_2906,cat_p_2905,cat_p_2904,cat_p_2903,cat_p_2902,cat_p_2901,cat_p_2900,cat_p_2899,cat_p_2898,cat_p_2897,cat_p_2896,cat_p_2895,cat_p_2894,cat_p_2893,cat_p_2892,cat_p_2891,cat_p_2890,cat_p_2889,cat_p_2888,cat_p_2887,cat_p_2886,cat_p_2885,cat_p_2884,cat_p_2883,cat_p_2878,cat_p_2877,cat_p_2874,cat_p_2873,cat_p_2869,cat_p_2868,cat_p_2867,cat_p_2864,cat_p_2863,cat_p_2862,cat_p_2861,cat_p_2860,cat_p_2859,cat_p_2858,cat_p_2857,cat_p_2856,cat_p_2855,cat_p_2854,cat_p_2853,cat_p_2852,cat_p_2851,cat_p_2849,cat_p_2848,cat_p_2847,cat_p_2846,cat_p_2845,cat_p_2844,cat_p_2843,cat_p_2842,cat_p_2841,cat_p_2840,cat_p_2839,cat_p_2838,cat_p_2837,cat_p_2836,cat_p_2835,cat_p_2834,cat_p_2833,cat_p_2832,cat_p_2831,cat_p_2830,cat_p_2829,cat_p_2828,cat_p_2827,cat_p_2826,cat_p_2825,cat_p_2824,cat_p_2823,cat_p_2822,cat_p_2821,cat_p_2820,cat_p_2819,cat_p_1717,cat_p_1716,cat_p_1634,cat_p_1625,cat_p_1249,cat_p_1207,cat_p_1206,cat_p_223,cat_p_82,cat_p_60,cat_p_56,cat_p_51,cat_p_3293,cat_p_3245,cat_p_3243,cat_p_3242,cat_p_2817,cat_p_2816,cat_p_2815,cat_p_2814,cat_p_2813,cat_p_2811,cat_p_2810,cat_p_2809,cat_p_2808,cat_p_2807,cat_p_2806,cat_p_2805,cat_p_2804,cat_p_2803,cat_p_2802,cat_p_2801,cat_p_2800,cat_p_2799,cat_p_2798,cat_p_2797,cat_p_2796,cat_p_2795,cat_p_2794,cat_p_2793,cat_p_2792,cat_p_2791,cat_p_2789,cat_p_2788,cat_p_2787,cat_p_2786,cat_p_2785,cat_p_2784,cat_p_2783,cat_p_2782,cat_p_2781,cat_p_2780,cat_p_2779,cat_p_2778,cat_p_2777,cat_p_2776,cat_p_2775,cat_p_2774,cat_p_2773,cat_p_2772,cat_p_2771,cat_p_2770,cat_p_2769,cat_p_2768,cat_p_2767,cat_p_2766,cat_p_2765,cat_p_2764,cat_p_2763,cat_p_2762,cat_p_2759,cat_p_2758,cat_p_2757,cat_p_2756,cat_p_2755,cat_p_2754,cat_p_2752,cat_p_2751,cat_p_2750,cat_p_2749,cat_p_2748,cat_p_2747,cat_p_2746,cat_p_2745,cat_p_2744,cat_p_2743,cat_p_2742,cat_p_2741,cat_p_2740,cat_p_2739,cat_p_2738,cat_p_2737,cat_p_2736,cat_p_2735,cat_p_2734,cat_p_2733,cat_p_2732,cat_p_2731,cat_p_2730,cat_p_2729,cat_p_2728,cat_p_2727,cat_p_2726,cat_p_2725,cat_p_2724,cat_p_2723,cat_p_2722,cat_p_2721,cat_p_2720,cat_p_2719,cat_p_2718,cat_p_2717,cat_p_2716,cat_p_2715,cat_p_2714,cat_p_2713,cat_p_2712,cat_p_2711,cat_p_2710,cat_p_2709,cat_p_2708,cat_p_2707,cat_p_2706,cat_p_2705,cat_p_2704,cat_p_2703,cat_p_2702,cat_p_2701,cat_p_2700,cat_p_2699,cat_p_2698,cat_p_2697,cat_p_2696,cat_p_2695,cat_p_2694,cat_p_2691,cat_p_2687,cat_p_2686,cat_p_2685,cat_p_2683,cat_p_2682,cat_p_2681,cat_p_2680,cat_p_2679,cat_p_2678,cat_p_2677,cat_p_2676,cat_p_2675,cat_p_2674,cat_p_2673,cat_p_2672,cat_p_2671,cat_p_2670,cat_p_2669,cat_p_2668,cat_p_2667,cat_p_2666,cat_p_2665,cat_p_2664,cat_p_2663,cat_p_2662,cat_p_2661,cat_p_2660,cat_p_2658,cat_p_2657,cat_p_2656,cat_p_2654,cat_p_2653,cat_p_2652,cat_p_2651,cat_p_2650,cat_p_2649,cat_p_2648,cat_p_2647,cat_p_2646,cat_p_2645,cat_p_2644,cat_p_2643,cat_p_2642,cat_p_2641,cat_p_2640,cat_p_2639,cat_p_2638,cat_p_2637,cat_p_2636,cat_p_2635,cat_p_2634,cat_p_2633,cat_p_2632,cat_p_2631,cat_p_2630,cat_p_2629,cat_p_2628,cat_p_2626,cat_p_2625,cat_p_2624,cat_p_2623,cat_p_2622,cat_p_2621,cat_p_2618,cat_p_2617,cat_p_2615,cat_p_2614,cat_p_2608,cat_p_2607,cat_p_2606,cat_p_2605,cat_p_2597,cat_p_2595,cat_p_2577,cat_p_2574,cat_p_2573,cat_p_2572,cat_p_2571,cat_p_2569,cat_p_2567,cat_p_2566,cat_p_2565,cat_p_2564,cat_p_2563,cat_p_2562,cat_p_2560,cat_p_2559,cat_p_2558,cat_p_2557,cat_p_2556,cat_p_2555,cat_p_2552,cat_p_2551,cat_p_2549,cat_p_2545,cat_p_2540,cat_p_2538,cat_p_2537,cat_p_2536,cat_p_2535,cat_p_2534,cat_p_2531,cat_p_2530,cat_p_2529,cat_p_2528,cat_p_2527,cat_p_2526,cat_p_2525,cat_p_2523,cat_p_2522,cat_p_2521,cat_p_2519,cat_p_2518,cat_p_2516,cat_p_2515,cat_p_2514,cat_p_2513,cat_p_2512,cat_p_2511,cat_p_2510,cat_p_2509,cat_p_2508,cat_p_2507,cat_p_2506,cat_p_2505,cat_p_2502,cat_p_2501,cat_p_2500,cat_p_2499,cat_p_2498,cat_p_2497,cat_p_2496,cat_p_2495,cat_p_2494,cat_p_2493,cat_p_2492,cat_p_2491,cat_p_2490,cat_p_2489,cat_p_2488,cat_p_2487,cat_p_2486,cat_p_2485,cat_p_2484,cat_p_2483,cat_p_2482,cat_p_2481,cat_p_2480,cat_p_2479,cat_p_2478,cat_p_2477,cat_p_2476,cat_p_2475,cat_p_2474,cat_p_2473,cat_p_2471,cat_p_2467,cat_p_2464,cat_p_2463,cat_p_2461,cat_p_2460,cat_p_2459,cat_p_2446,cat_p_2445,cat_p_2444,cat_p_2443,cat_p_2442,cat_p_2439,cat_p_2438,cat_p_2437,cat_p_2436,cat_p_2435,cat_p_2434,cat_p_2433,cat_p_2432,cat_p_2431,cat_p_2430,cat_p_2428,cat_p_2427,cat_p_2426,cat_p_2425,cat_p_2424,cat_p_2422,cat_p_2421,cat_p_2420,cat_p_2419,cat_p_2418,cat_p_2417,cat_p_2416,cat_p_2415,cat_p_2414,cat_p_2413,cat_p_2412,cat_p_2411,cat_p_2410,cat_p_2409,cat_p_2408,cat_p_2407,cat_p_2402,cat_p_2400,cat_p_2399,cat_p_2398,cat_p_2397,cat_p_2395,cat_p_2394,cat_p_2393,cat_p_2391,cat_p_2385,cat_p_2383,cat_p_2380,cat_p_2373,cat_p_2372,cat_p_2371,cat_p_2370,cat_p_2369,cat_p_2368,cat_p_2367,cat_p_2366,cat_p_2365,cat_p_2364,cat_p_2363,cat_p_2362,cat_p_2361,cat_p_2359,cat_p_2358,cat_p_2356,cat_p_2355,cat_p_2354,cat_p_2352,cat_p_2351,cat_p_2349,cat_p_2348,cat_p_2346,cat_p_2345,cat_p_2344,cat_p_2343,cat_p_2342,cat_p_2341,cat_p_2340,cat_p_2339,cat_p_2338,cat_p_2337,cat_p_2336,cat_p_2335,cat_p_2333,cat_p_2332,cat_p_2331,cat_p_2330,cat_p_2328,cat_p_2325,cat_p_2323,cat_p_2322,cat_p_2319,cat_p_2318,cat_p_2317,cat_p_2316,cat_p_2315,cat_p_2314,cat_p_2313,cat_p_2312,cat_p_2311,cat_p_2310,cat_p_2309,cat_p_2308,cat_p_2307,cat_p_2306,cat_p_2305,cat_p_2304,cat_p_2303,cat_p_2302,cat_p_2301,cat_p_2300,cat_p_2299,cat_p_2298,cat_p_2297,cat_p_2296,cat_p_2291,cat_p_2289,cat_p_2288,cat_p_2287,cat_p_2286,cat_p_2285,cat_p_2284,cat_p_2283,cat_p_2282,cat_p_2281,cat_p_2280,cat_p_2279,cat_p_2278,cat_p_2277,cat_p_2276,cat_p_2275,cat_p_2274,cat_p_2272,cat_p_2271,cat_p_2268,cat_p_2267,cat_p_2263,cat_p_2262,cat_p_2261,cat_p_2260,cat_p_2257,cat_p_2256,cat_p_2254,cat_p_2253,cat_p_2252,cat_p_2251,cat_p_2250,cat_p_2249,cat_p_2248,cat_p_2247,cat_p_2246,cat_p_2245,cat_p_2243,cat_p_2242,cat_p_2241,cat_p_2240,cat_p_2239,cat_p_2226,cat_p_2221,cat_p_2183,cat_p_2182,cat_p_2177,cat_p_2176,cat_p_2175,cat_p_2167,cat_p_2165,cat_p_2164,cat_p_2163,cat_p_2158,cat_p_2153,cat_p_2149,cat_p_2147,cat_p_2146,cat_p_2138,cat_p_2137,cat_p_2136,cat_p_2135,cat_p_2134,cat_p_2133,cat_p_2131,cat_p_2130,cat_p_2129,cat_p_2128,cat_p_2127,cat_p_2126,cat_p_2125,cat_p_2124,cat_p_2110,cat_p_2109,cat_p_2108,cat_p_2106,cat_p_2096,cat_p_2095,cat_p_2094,cat_p_2089,cat_p_2088,cat_p_2087,cat_p_2086,cat_p_2085,cat_p_2080,cat_p_2078,cat_p_2077,cat_p_2076,cat_p_2075,cat_p_2072,cat_p_2071,cat_p_2069,cat_p_2063,cat_p_2062,cat_p_2061,cat_p_2060,cat_p_2057,cat_p_2056,cat_p_2053,cat_p_2052,cat_p_2051,cat_p_2047,cat_p_2042,cat_p_2038,cat_p_2035,cat_p_2030,cat_p_2023,cat_p_2020,cat_p_2019,cat_p_2018,cat_p_2017,cat_p_2016,cat_p_2015,cat_p_2014,cat_p_2012,cat_p_2009,cat_p_2004,cat_p_1999,cat_p_1997,cat_p_1996,cat_p_1995,cat_p_1994,cat_p_1988,cat_p_1987,cat_p_1985,cat_p_1984,cat_p_1983,cat_p_1982,cat_p_1981,cat_p_1980,cat_p_1979,cat_p_1955,cat_p_1948,cat_p_1946,cat_p_1937,cat_p_1936,cat_p_1931,cat_p_1930,cat_p_1929,cat_p_1916,cat_p_1915,cat_p_1914,cat_p_1911,cat_p_1907,cat_p_1905,cat_p_1872,cat_p_1869,cat_p_1864,cat_p_1861,cat_p_1809,cat_p_1808,cat_p_1772,cat_p_1771,cat_p_1751,cat_p_1738,cat_p_1737,cat_p_1734,cat_p_1733,cat_p_1732,cat_p_1731,cat_p_1730,cat_p_1729,cat_p_1728,cat_p_1725,cat_p_1724,cat_p_1723,cat_p_1722,cat_p_1721,cat_p_1718,cat_p_1713,cat_p_1707,cat_p_1706,cat_p_1705,cat_p_1692,cat_p_1686,cat_p_1604,cat_p_1603,cat_p_1602,cat_p_1584,cat_p_1581,cat_p_1580,cat_p_1579,cat_p_1554,cat_p_1553,cat_p_1535,cat_p_1493,cat_p_1491,cat_p_1489,cat_p_1482,cat_p_1481,cat_p_1480,cat_p_1477,cat_p_1471,cat_p_1469,cat_p_1465,cat_p_1461,cat_p_1456,cat_p_1450,cat_p_1443,cat_p_1441,cat_p_1438,cat_p_1436,cat_p_1435,cat_p_1434,cat_p_1433,cat_p_1432,cat_p_1431,cat_p_1429,cat_p_1419,cat_p_1418,cat_p_1412,cat_p_1411,cat_p_1372,cat_p_1371,cat_p_1369,cat_p_1365,cat_p_1360,cat_p_1357,cat_p_1356,cat_p_1351,cat_p_1333,cat_p_1332,cat_p_1331,cat_p_1330,cat_p_1329,cat_p_1328,cat_p_1325,cat_p_1323,cat_p_1322,cat_p_1321,cat_p_1310,cat_p_1309,cat_p_1308,cat_p_1306,cat_p_1304,cat_p_1303,cat_p_1301,cat_p_1300,cat_p_1299,cat_p_1295,cat_p_1294,cat_p_1273,cat_p_1266,cat_p_1260,cat_p_1259,cat_p_1258,cat_p_1257,cat_p_1256,cat_p_1255,cat_p_1254,cat_p_1253,cat_p_1252,cat_p_1251,cat_p_1250,cat_p_1235,cat_p_1223,cat_p_1210,cat_p_1202,cat_p_1201,cat_p_1196,cat_p_1193,cat_p_1192,cat_p_1185,cat_p_1184,cat_p_1183,cat_p_1182,cat_p_1175,cat_p_1166,cat_p_1164,cat_p_1162,cat_p_1136,cat_p_1116,cat_p_1112,cat_p_1108,cat_p_1107,cat_p_1106,cat_p_1102,cat_p_1098,cat_p_1097,cat_p_1088,cat_p_1084,cat_p_1082,cat_p_1073,cat_p_1070,cat_p_1069,cat_p_1068,cat_p_1066,cat_p_1064,cat_p_1057,cat_p_1053,cat_p_1050,cat_p_1044,cat_p_1043,cat_p_994,cat_p_992,cat_p_989,cat_p_988,cat_p_987,cat_p_979,cat_p_978,cat_p_977,cat_p_969,cat_p_965,cat_p_964,cat_p_963,cat_p_962,cat_p_959,cat_p_958,cat_p_957,cat_p_956,cat_p_620,cat_p_547,cat_p_545,cat_p_543,cat_p_535,cat_p_510,cat_p_500,cat_p_499,cat_p_497,cat_p_495,cat_p_491,cat_p_489,cat_p_488,cat_p_486,cat_p_481,cat_p_464,cat_p_462,cat_p_459,cat_p_458,cat_p_457,cat_p_449,cat_p_448,cat_p_447,cat_p_444,cat_p_442,cat_p_439,cat_p_437,cat_p_435,cat_p_434,cat_p_433,cat_p_426,cat_p_425,cat_p_422,cat_p_421,cat_p_419,cat_p_417,cat_p_415,cat_p_413,cat_p_412,cat_p_404,cat_p_400,cat_p_399,cat_p_398,cat_p_397,cat_p_396,cat_p_393,cat_p_392,cat_p_387,cat_p_385,cat_p_352,cat_p_338,cat_p_337,cat_p_332,cat_p_328,cat_p_323,cat_p_319,cat_p_318,cat_p_317,cat_p_316,cat_p_314,cat_p_293,cat_p_290,cat_p_274,cat_p_273,cat_p_266,cat_p_259,cat_p_250,cat_p_249,cat_p_248,cat_p_247,cat_p_245,cat_p_240,cat_p_239,cat_p_236,cat_p_235,cat_p_234,cat_p_232,cat_p_229,cat_p_225,cat_p_222,cat_p_216,cat_p_211,cat_p_209,cat_p_205,cat_p_201,cat_p_196,cat_p_195,cat_p_194,cat_p_193,cat_p_192,cat_p_189,cat_p_186,cat_p_185,cat_p_169,cat_p_144,cat_p_143,cat_p_141,cat_p_96,cat_p_94,cat_p_90,cat_p_85
```

This is pretty long and seems to crash Apache / FPM.

I found some GitHub issues, but i am unclear of the current status.

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6401
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8815

Is this know to others? Is there a proper fix? What is the root cause of it?

Comment: Happens with PHP7.2-fpm too

Comment: And php7.3-fpm too.

Answer (score 3):

We are giving up the cache invalidation functionality that X-Magento-Tags enables using the following patch to clear the header:

```
--- vendor/magento/framework/App/PageCache/Kernel.php
+++ vendor/magento/framework/App/PageCache/Kernel.php
@@ -141,9 +141,7 @@
                 $tags = $tagsHeader ? explode(',', $tagsHeader->getFieldValue()) : [];

                 $response->clearHeader('Set-Cookie');
-                if ($this->state->getMode() != AppState::MODE_DEVELOPER) {
-                    $response->clearHeader('X-Magento-Tags');
-                }
+                $response->clearHeader('X-Magento-Tags'); #47631 HOTFIX
                 if (!headers_sent()) {
                     header_remove('Set-Cookie');
                 }
@@ -156,6 +154,7 @@
                 );
             }
         }
+        $response->clearHeader('X-Magento-Tags'); #65734 HOTFIX
     }

     /**
```

It's not a good solution in case you want to keep this functionality but it enables us to continue working.

Comment: Alan Storm writes about another option of increasing `LimitRequestFieldSize` in his article https://alanstorm.com/fixing-x-magento-tags-too-large-errors/ maybe that helps too.